# Monogame tutorials /walkthroughs for normal Windows 7 development (not Windows 8, Android or iOS)

Tags: c#, monogame

Can somebody point me to some good Monogame walkthroughs or tutorials?

The reason I am asking this question is because when I try to create a new project in VS2012, I get the following options

[image: image1]

But all the tutorials or walkthroughs (like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx) one) have the following options and develop using xaml -

[image: img2]

Now, I guess this is because I am using Windows 7. So can somebody give me tutorials that are actually targeted to my case.

NOTE: I am trying to develop simple and normal games for Windows 7, nothing fancy like XBox, Windows 8 or Android. Where can I find appropriate getting started walkthroughs for my situation?

Comment: If you're just developing games for windows 7 you may as well use XNA, not MonoGame (the cross compatible open source re-creation of XNA).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett But isnt XNA dead?

Comment: You can still use it tough. If you're only targeting platforms that it supports (and will only target those) then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few MonoGame tutorials listed on the forums here:
https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/439595

And a related post about ideas for new MonoGame tutorials here:
https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/439728

As previously mentioned, the MonoGame API is syntactically compatible with XNA so most XNA tutorials will also be helpful.

There is some trickiness around dealing with content, the simplest method in my opinion is to just add it to the Content folder, set it to Content / Copy if newer in the properties window and refer to it with the file extension in code (unless it's an XNB file).

MonoGame is a great project and I highly recommend it if you want to make games for many platforms, something you may want to do sooner or later. However, it still has a few missing features compared to XNA so life may be easier in the short term, while you're learning if you stick with XNA.

Last point, your nearly there anyway, based on your first screenshot I would choose the MonoGame Windows OpenGL Project if you want to target windows 7. Learn how to render your first sprite and you may decide that proceeding with MonoGame is not so bad after all.

Answer (score 1):

Most MonoGame tutorials will deal with Windows 8 or non-windows. This is because MonoGame was created as an alternative to XNA for easy porting from XNA-supported platforms (such as windows 7) to non-XNA supported platforms (such as a Windows Store App).

Note that you can still use XNA in Windows 8, but you'd be creating a desktop app, not a Windows Store App.

Comment: Best is subjective. Right now I'd say XNA, as MonoGame doesn't yet have a fully compatible pipeline (so you'd need XNA to produce content files anyway). The argument against that would be that since you aren't going from XNA to MonoGame you can use their alternative (look at docs for this, I've not used it).

Comment: well ok, I will go for XNA then. But still, do you know of any monogame tutorial for my case?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Look for tutorials that don't create a XAML based xna game and simply deal with creating a normal desktop project.

Answer (score 0):

A great resource of example is the multi-platform sample project which contains several examples made to work on all platforms

https://github.com/Mono-Game/MonoGame.Samples

The platformer sample is on all platforms and the rest are in progress, but all show a great way to setup your project ready to tackle all the platforms out there!